# How can i render the data value in a h1 element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can i render the data value in a h1 element? i have created a simple function its work is to just console random meme name and that function works fine but i want that that random name which iam consoling display in a h1 element in my web page so how can i do that? i want that when i click the button that random name display in my web page in a h1 element not in console

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import memesData from './memesData';
import './MainContent.css';

function MainContent() {



   function getMemeImage() {

      const memesArray = memesData.data.memes
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length)
      const n = memesArray[randomNumber].name
      console.log(n)
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={getMemeImage}> Click me </button>
      </div>
   )
}

export default MainContent
```

## I tried

its not working correct me anyone

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import memesData from './memesData';
import './MainContent.css';

function MainContent() {

   const [data, setData] = useState('')

   function getMemeImage() {

      const memesArray = memesData.data.memes
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length)
      const n = memesArray[randomNumber].name
      console.log(n)
      setData(data + n)
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={getMemeImage}> Click me </button>
         <h1>{setData}</h1>
      </div>
   )
}

export default MainContent
```

Comment: You should look at some React examples on how to use/update state.

Comment: Wouldn't old fashion javascript work? ```document.getElementById("your-h1-id").innerHTML = "text or html";```

Comment: @Andy i tired correct me check my edited question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import memesData from './memesData';
import './MainContent.css';

function MainContent() {

const [state, setState] = useState();

   function getMemeImage() {

      const memesArray = memesData.data.memes;
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length);
      const n = memesArray[randomNumber].name;
      setState(n);
      console.log(n)
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={getMemeImage}> Click me </button>
         <h1>{state}</h1>
      </div>
   )
}

export default MainContent
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to let `getMemeImage` return the value, so you can easily pass it to `setData` end as initial value.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
   
   const names = [ "foo", "bar", "joe", "someone", "else" ];

   function getMemeImage() {
      const memesArray = [ ...names ]
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length)
      const n = memesArray[randomNumber]
      return n;
   }
   
   const [data, setData] = useState(getMemeImage())

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={() => setData(getMemeImage())}> Click me </button>
         <h1>{data}</h1>
      </div>
   )
}
   
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Wow a sweet example Thanks for this..

Comment: You probably don't need to make a copy of `names` there as it's not being used to update state.